# Vertical Select in Word Doesn't Work - Alt Key Opens Research Window

Tags: microsoft-word, selection

It says in many places that I can do vertical selection in Word by holding down the Alt key while I drag the mouse. However for me this just opens a research window.

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Which Windows version and which Office version? What search window? - A screenshot would help. Does this happen when booting in Safe Mode?

Comment: Just tested that I can do this in Word 2016.

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2019 - Click mouse at the place you want to start. Press alt. Keep left mouse key and Alt pressed and move mouse cursor to the end.

[image]

gray rectangular block is appearing selected above in a word file.